# Сравнение коллекции Laravel

Tags: laravel

Получаю 2 коллекции, у каждой есть пара ключ/значение к примеру id=1

```
$collectionA = User::all();

$collectionB = Base::all();
```

Как сравнить 2 коллекции по id и вернуть коллекцию только с повторяющимися значения ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$collectionA = User::get()->keyBy('id');

$collectionB = Base::get()->keyBy('id');

$collection = $collectionA->intersectByKeys($collectionB);
```